# php: use variable name to display specific image on diffrent page

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql

Php beginner here. I have php loop on page to display images (basically a gallery) and each image has a title displayed below. Those titles are links to second page where only one image is shown.
The problem is that every link has a different name (value of name is specific /ID of image).

```
<form action="image_link.php" method="post">
<?php>
$sql_select = "SELECT * FROM images ORDER BY data DESC"; 
$sql_table_selected = mysql_query($sql_select);
while ($table_row = mysql_fetch_array($sql_table_selected)){
    echo "<div class=\"galery-1-3\"><figure>";
    echo "<img src=\"" . $table_row['file_path'] . "\" />";
    echo "<figcaption><a href=image_link.php name=\"" . $table_row['ID'] . "\">" . $table_row['tytul'] . "</a></figcaption></figure></div>";
    }
?>
```

I'm getting a single image displayed but no matter what title I click, I always get last image from the table. How can I catch a specific ID on `image_link.php`, or should I use some flexible kind of address like `/image_link.php?id=34`. I don't know where to start.

image_link.php contains basically the same code without the loop:

```
$sql_select = "SELECT * FROM images WHERE ID = $SomehowGetID"; 
$sql_table_selected = mysql_query($sql_select);
$table_row = mysql_fetch_array($sql_table_selected);
    echo "<div class=\"galery-big\"><figure>";
    echo "<img src=\"" . $table_row['file_path'] . "\" />";
    echo "<figcaption>" . $table_row['tytul'] . "</figcaption></figure></div>";
```

Thanks in advance for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need for a form

first script :

```
<?php
$sql_select = "SELECT * FROM images ORDER BY data DESC"; 
$sql_table_selected = mysql_query($sql_select);
while ($table_row = mysql_fetch_array($sql_table_selected)){
    echo "<div class=\"galery-1-3\"><figure>";
    echo "<img src=\"" . $table_row['file_path'] . "\" />";
    echo "<figcaption><a href=\"image_link.php?id=" . $table_row['ID'] 
     . "\" name=\"" . $table_row['ID']
     . "\">" . $table_row['tytul'] . "</a></figcaption></figure></div>";
}
?>
```

second script

```
$SomehowGetID=$_GET['id'];
$sql_select = "SELECT * FROM images WHERE ID = $SomehowGetID"; 
$sql_table_selected = mysql_query($sql_select); 
$table_row = mysql_fetch_array($sql_table_selected);
    echo "<div class=\"galery-big\"><figure>";
    echo "<img src=\"" . $table_row['file_path'] . "\" />";
    echo "<figcaption>" . $table_row['tytul'] 
    . "</figcaption></figure>   </div>";
```

I'd advice you though to use prepared statement instead of simple query constructions.

Comment: I had to use question mark instead of ampersand in `image_link.php&id` and i don't know really why, but it worked. Thanks

Comment: Oh my bad, yes, it is a "?" , i'll modify it.

Answer (score 0):

Change query to:

```
$sql_select = "SELECT * FROM images WHERE ID =" $_GET['id'];
```

Comment: why cant he learn this way? What is the problem if he wants to play with it this way??

Comment: Security would be the main concern. I did not say anything was wrong with the answer but it is better practice.

Comment: agreed yes prepared statement is the best practice.

Answer (score 0):

```
echo 
"<figcaption>
<a href='image_link.php?id=$table_row[ID]' name='$table_row[ID]'>"
 .$table_row['tytul'] ."
</a>
</figcaption>
</figure></div>";
```

You need to pass the **id** as a parameter in your href with **$table_row[ID]** as value.

**In image_link.php**

Use:

```
$sql_select = "SELECT * FROM images WHERE ID = '$_GET[ID]'";
```

Answer (score 0):

You had the right idea by saying that you want to pass the id of the image.
your code should looks like this :

```
<form action="image_link.php" method="post">
<?php>
$sql_select = "SELECT * FROM images ORDER BY data DESC"; 
$sql_table_selected = mysql_query($sql_select);
while ($table_row = mysql_fetch_array($sql_table_selected)){
    echo "<div class=\"galery-1-3\"><figure>";
    echo "<img src=\"" . $table_row['file_path'] . "\" />";
    echo "<figcaption><a href=image_link.php?id=" . intval($table_row['ID']) . "name=\"" . $table_row['ID'] . "\">" . $table_row['tytul'] . "</a></figcaption></figure></div>";
    }
?>
```

image_link.php:

```
$sql_select = "SELECT * FROM images WHERE ID =" . mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['id']); 
$sql_table_selected = mysql_query($sql_select);
$table_row = mysql_fetch_array($sql_table_selected);
echo "<div class=\"galery-big\"><figure>";
echo "<img src=\"" . $table_row['file_path'] . "\" />";
echo "<figcaption>" . $table_row['tytul'] . "</figcaption></figure></div>";
```

Please note that the use of mysql_* function is highly deprecated, you should use mysqli extention instead